# Linear congruence system of 2 variables

Tags: proof-verification, modular-arithmetic

The question is: Find $x, y ∈ \mathbb Z_{11}$ that satisfy the simultaneous system of linear equations

> $[5]_{11} x +[2] _{11}  y = [6] _{11}$
>
> $[4]_{11}  x + y = [2] _{11}$

So I rewrote this as

$5x + 2y  = [6] _{11}$ ,

$4x + y  = [2] _{11} $,
which is equivalent to

$5x + 2y = 6$ (mod $11) (1)$

$4x +  y = 2$ (mod $11) (2)$

$2(2) - (1)$ gives $3x = -2$ (mod $11) ⇒ 3x = 11k - 2$, for some integer $k$.

Then $(1) + (2)$ gives $9x + 3y = 8 ($mod $11) ⇒ 3(3x) + 3y = 8 ($mod $11) ⇒ 33k - 6 + 3y = 8$ (mod $11) ⇒ 3y + 33k = 14$ (mod $11) = 3 ($mod $11) ⇒ y + 11k = 1 ($mod $11) ⇒ y = 11m + 1 ⇒ y = [1] _{11}  $

Then $(1)$ gives $5x + 2 = 6 ($mod $11)$, and, by noticing that $17 = 5(3) + 2$ and $17 = 6 ($mod $11)$, I got $x = [3] _{11} $.

So, first of all, is my rewriting the congruence class equations as modular equations correct? And, if so, is my solution right, and are there any more solutions?

Comment: What do you mean by numbers in brackets?

Comment: If you mean in square brackets, then it's the residue of a number modulo 11. If you mean (1), (2), I used these to denote the 1st and 2nd equation of the system, respectively.

Comment: $\Bbb Z_{11}$ is a field, so solving linear equations over it works the same way it does in classical fields like $\,\Bbb Q,\ \Bbb R,\ \Bbb C,\,$ etc.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't seen fields in my course yet, but do you mean that, since this is a linear system, my pair of solutions is the only one?